# Please check the sql query and need help in solving the second one

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
Student (Id, Name, Country) 
Course (CrsCode, CrsName, Type, Instructor)
Results(Id, CrsCode, Grade)
```

Key fields are underlined. 
The Type field indicated the course type, e.g. MGMT, ENG, SCI etc.

the following are the two queries based on above problem

1 Find the Id of students who take MGMT or ENG course.

Sol.

```
 SELECT S.Id
 FROM STUDENT S,COURSE C
 WHERE C.type = "MGMT" OR C.type = "ENG"
```

b. Find the Id of students who take every MGMT course or take every SYSC course.
I am Stucked up with term "every" in the above query and please check if the first one is correct or not

Comment: Can you provide us a sample of data that you have in your tables?

Comment: Is this `ID` field in `Results` table referring back to `ID` field in `Students` table ?

Comment: Poor question without reproducible example nor DDL of tables. Provide more clues and eventually post on sqlfiddle an example.

Comment: @M.Ali Yes. Sorry I forgot to underline the key Fields
So, Id and CrsCode are the key underlined key fields

Comment: Also What RDBMS you are using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle ???

Comment: @M.Ali I am using Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not correct. You need to make use of all three. The Results table links student to the course which then contains your type code.

Using joins:

```
SELECT s.ID
FROM STUDENT s
JOIN RESULTS r on r.ID = s.ID
JOIN COURSE c on c.CrsCode = r.CrsCode
WHERE c.type = "MGMT" OR c.type = "ENG"
```

Or the multiple table select:

```
SELECT s.ID
FROM STUDENT s, RESULTS r, COURSE c 
WHERE r.ID = s.ID AND c.CrsCode = r.CrsCode AND (c.type = "MGMT" OR c.type = "ENG")
```

Comment: Thanks alot.
In the multiple table, Have you used Foreign key ??